# Run first request multiple times and other request single time in a single thread

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I Have 5 HTTP request in single thread, I want to run first request multiple times and then other request only single time

I can't use multiple thread as all request are depends on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put first request under [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with Loop Count as the times you want to repeat

> JMeter will loop through them a certain number of times, in addition to the loop value you specified for the Thread Group. For example, if you add one HTTP Request to a Loop Controller with a loop count of two, and configure the Thread Group loop count to three, JMeter will send a total of 2 * 3 = 6 HTTP Requests.

Choose request(s) you want to execute multiple times and then:

Right Click -> Insert Parent -> Logic Controller -> Loop Controller

Comment: Loop Controller can be added for the entire thread, not for the particular request, Can you please tell how to add loop controller for particular http request

Comment: @Rock Right Click -> Insert Parent -> Logic Controller -> Loop Controller

Comment: Thank you very much user7294900,It solved my problem and got the solution but I have the scenario where I have 10 http request, first request should run single time and other 9 request should run muliple times, Now If I pass No. of thread 100 then also my first request should run single times and other 9 request should run 100 times, please help in this.

Comment: @Rock similarly you can mark multiple requests and insert Loop controller as parent

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. Put the request which needs to be run only once under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller), this way the Sampler will be executed only during first iteration of the Thread Group

   [image]
2. If you want more complex/flexible criteria - put the request which needs to be executed only once under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/), this way you will be able to specify whatever criteria you want. For example if you want to run a Sampler only during 5th iteration use the following condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${__jm__Thread Group__idx}" == "5",)}
   ```

   [image]

   this way the sampler(s) which is (are) under the If Controller will be executed only if the condition is met:

   [image]